# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, remotewebdriver

I'm try to launch electron application on remote PC which is connected as node to selenium grid.previously its worked fine.But now i'm getting this error "DevToolActivePort file doesn't exist"

```
    System.out.println("launch application in windows PC");     
    capa  = new DesiredCapabilities();

    capa.setBrowserName("chrome");
    File file = new File("path\\to\\file\\.exe"); 
    URL server = new URL("http://ip_of_remote_pc:4444/wd/hub"); 

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setBinary(file);   //Sets the path to the Chrome executable
    capa.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    driver2 = new RemoteWebDriver(server, capa); //launch the application
    System.out.println("launching application in remote PC");
    driver2.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);   
    System.out.println("Application launched");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-d)

Comment: I'm tried those solutions,but they didn't help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download Chrome driver for electron ,,or visit this 
https://github.com/electron/electron/releases
Install the chromedriver here and it will work

Answer (score 4):

Just add the following ChromeOptions it will solve the problem,

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArgument("--headless");
options.addArgument("--no-sandbox");  // Bypass OS security model
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to windows os only
```